# Filtering collection by _t on property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I already implemented with mongo/c# a scenario where I store on the same collection different types of classes. Everything works great and I can do this in the end:

```
var collection = _mongoDb.GetCollection<TLogType>(CollectionNames.Logs).OfType<TLogType>();
```

Now I needed a similar functionality but for properties. Basically, I have collection (normal one, not polymorphic) which has an array of contacts. I wanted each item in the array to be of a specific contact type. The document I came up with and it is working looks like this (smaller for brevity):

```
Contacts" : [ 
    {
        "_t" : [ 
            "Contact", 
            "ExternalContact"
        ],
        "Role" : "Product Emergency",
        "Name" : "Fred",
        "Email" : "fred@gmail",
        "Phone" : "1231",
        "Availability" : "",
    }, 
    {
        "_t" : [ 
            "Contact", 
            "InternalContact"
        ],
        "Role" : "Manager",
        "Name" : "Mickey"
    }
]
```

What I want now is to retrieve contacts by type. We have the `OfType<TResult>` but it's only available to MongoQueryable. So, something like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetContacts<TContactType>(CancellationToken token) where TContactType : Contact
{

    var collection = _mongoDb.GetCollection<Person>(CollectionNames.Person)();

    var projectedListOfContacts =
        await collection.Find(
            s => s.Contacts != null && 
            s.Contacts.OfType<TContactType> // how to filter by type on a property?
        )
            .Project(dto => dto.Contacts).
            .ToListAsync(token);

    ...
}
```

Any way to do this without having to get all contacts and work with them in memory?

The relevant classes are:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}
}

public abstract class Contact : IContact
{
    public string Role { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    protected Contact(string role, string name)
    {
        Role = role ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(role));
        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }
}

public class ExternalContact : Contact
{

    public string Email { get; private set; }   
    public string Phone { get; private set; }   
    public string Availability { get; private set; }

    public ExternalContact(string role, string name, string email, string phone, string availability)
        : base(role, name)
    {
        Email = email ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));
        Phone = phone ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(phone));
        Availability = availability;
    }
}
```

**Update:** The answer helped me figure it out.. so in the end I could do this:

```
var contacts =
await Collection.Find(s => s.Contacts != null)
    .Project(dto => dto.Contacts.OfType<TContactType>())
    .ToListAsync(token);
```

Turned out that the requirements changed.. and the Contact array will always have at least one of each type. So there was no reason to filter.. but I took advantage of the Projection that only returned the type I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just taking a wild shot here but I believe this may be what you are looking for, but it's hard to be sure without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```
        var nullFilter = Builders<Person<TContactType>>.Filter.Ne(person => person.Contacts, null);
        var typeFilter = Builders<Person<TContactType>>.Filter.OfType<Contact, TContactType>(person => person.Contacts);
        var combinedFilter = Builders<Person<TContactType>>.Filter.And(nullFilter, typeFilter);

        var projectedListOfContact = collection.Find(combinedFilter).Project(dto => dto.Contacts).ToListAsync(token);
```

**Updated Builder**

```
var query = Builders<Person>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Contacts, Builders<Contact>.Filter.OfType<ExternalContact>());
collection.Find(query);
```

Which of course can also be used with your generic T.

This should return `find({ "Contacts" : { "$elemMatch" : { "_t" : "ExternalContact" } } })`

Comment: The second line might be the right one, but I can't find a way to get it working:
var typeFilter = Builders<Person>.Filter.OfType<Contact, TContactType>(s => s.Contacts);
It complains that can't convert IEnumerable<Contact> to Contact. If I add the generic argument to make the compiler happy, then I get 0 results. The actual query on mongo makes sense why didn't return anything:
filter_Contacts._t:
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Greentube.Nrgs.Hub.Domain.Sites.SiteInternalContact, Nrgs.Hub.Domain]]

Comment: @jpgrassi, could you please edit your post and add a bit more code such as your full person and contact class of possible.

Comment: Sure, added the classes that made up the Person collection.

Comment: This query returns the data I want: db.Person.find({},{ Contacts: { $elemMatch: { _t: "ExternalContact" } } } ) But I can't get it working with the c# driver.

Comment: With a little tweaking could make it working. Will accept this. Thanks.

Comment: @jpgrassi, don't forget to post your final result to help others :)

Comment: Sure. Checkout the update and what I came up with :). Comparing the queries generated, they look pretty much similar.